# none of my onClick listener is working, my phone is not responding to any of the four onClick listeners

Tags: android

after building my project none of my onClick listener is working, my phone is not responding to any of the four onClick listeners after installing the SDK .

This is my XML code for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers"
        android:onClick="openNumbersList"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/family"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_family"
        android:text="@string/category_family"
        android:onClick="openFamilyMembersList"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:text="@string/category_colors"
        android:onClick="openColorsActivity"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phrases"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_phrases"
        android:text="@string/category_phrases"
        android:onClick="openPhrasesActivity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my java code for the MainActivity.

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openNumbersList(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void openFamilyMembersList(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, FamilyMembersActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void openColorsActivity(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ColorsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void openPhrasesActivity(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, PhrasesActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

kindly let me know the mistake, I am also not getting anysort of error in the logs.

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: can you share me min and max sdk version

Comment: can you post CategoryStyle

Comment: no i am not getting any error.

Answer (score 2):

try to add one more attribute

```
android:clickable="true"
```

inside your `textviews`

Comment: by default it is considered as clickable="true", and i tried making this change even after that, its still not working.

Comment: please share min and max sdk version

Comment: android 4.4 to 8.1

Comment: are you sure you tried with onclick:true attribute because by default onclick for buttons only true and for textview it will be false

Comment: i tried it brother but it is still the same, but i tried for  android:clickable="true", i dont know about onClick:true, please elaborate.